# Why action controllers in Play are singleton objects?

Tags: scala, playframework

In Play 2.3 tutorial is is written that

> A Controller is nothing more than a singleton object that generates Action values.

And the following example is provided.

```
package controllers
import play.api.mvc._

object Application extends Controller {
 def index = Action {
   Ok("It works!")
 }
}
```

Everything is ok and clear with this but I was thinking about concurrency and how exactly this singleton object controller stands from the performance point of view?
Can anyone familiar good enough with Play internal architecture explain why should a controller be singleton and how multiple user requests are going through this singleton object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Play Design, Action is stateless: it gets a request and raises a result. Controller define `Action`s that can be called from router (or by chaining from other actions), which still doesn't imply having a state. Being stateless,  concurrent can't raise issue accessing shared data (from instance state).

That's why controller can be a singleton/stateless instance (or not, it doesn't bother Play controller being defined as `class`).

Comment: that's not true that it doesn't bother Play controller being defined as a class. If I change in the source code the "object" to "class"it gets not compiled and complains:
`object Application is not a member of package controllers
Note: class Application exists, but it has no companion object.`

Comment: That's related to router, having something like `GET / controllers.Application.index` as route. Not related to Controller/Action design, or concurrency/performance. You can have actions defined in a class a route to those one from other controller of from view.

Comment: but again, the error caused me not to be able to have a reverse router from my template if it is a `class`